# How to auto update a ViewController after user log in

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, viewcontroller

I have a ViewController **MenuViewController** which is only initiated when app is first launched. After a user logged in I will go to another ViewController but in the mean time I want to set a label in that MenuViewController like **Hi username**

How can i do it? I'm not so experienced in swift. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear. What object controls login? Is it `MenuViewController` or some other object? My assumption is that `MenuViewController` does not handle login, or the answer would be trivial. My answer below is based on that assumption:

There are lots of ways to do this.

You could set up your login class to have a delegate. Have the delegate conform to a `LoginStatus` protocol. That protocol would have a method, didLogIn().

When your `MenuViewController` initiates a login, it would create a login object and set itself as the delegate.

The login object would invoke it's delegate's `didLogIn()` method once login was complete. The `MenuViewController`'s implementation of the `didLogIn()` method could display your hello message.

(If you need information about the login like the username, or need to report status like log in Ok, log out, log in failure, etc, you would need to modify your `LoginStatus` protocol methods so it could pass that extra info to the delegate.

You could also have your login object broadcast a notification manager notification didLogIn. Then your `MenuViewController` could listen for that notification.

You could write your login class to take a completion block that it invokes once login is complete.

That is 3 different ways to handle this right off the top of my head. There are no doubt other ways as well.

Comment: Yes. It is MenuViewController. My target is i will inititate login from LoginViewController (another viewcontroller) and that will trigger MenuviewController to update according to userinfo.

Answer (score 0):

- Add `UILabel` in your stroyboard
- Drag an outlet to `MenuViewController`, something like :

  ```
  @IBOutlet weak var topLabel: UILabel!
  ```
- In `MenuViewController` `viewDidLoad` method add the following:

  ```
  let displayName = "username"
  self.topLabel.text = "Hi \(displayName),"
  ```

Comment: That only works if the `MenuViewController` is only invoked when login is complete. The OP doesn't say what object is responsible for login, or when login takes place. His statement "MenuViewController... is only initiated when app is first launched. " implies that `MenuViewController` is invoked at app launch, before login has begin. In that case your solution would not work.

Comment: @Duncan C I agree that the question is not clear, and not showing what does OP tried to do. It made sense to me that if the program shows the `username` name, the user should be logged in.